# What's wrong with int main()?

Tags: c, prototype, program-entry-point

I can't count the number of times I've seen C code out there and here on SO that defines *main* as

```
int main() { ...
```

When I compile it with

```
gcc -ansi -pedantic -Wstrict-prototypes -Werror foo.c
```

it errors out with

```
foo.c:2: warning: function declaration isn't a prototype
```

Why is it that

```
int main(void)
```

is required to make the error go away?

Comment: `-Wstrict-prototypes -Werror` You told it to not accept `int main()`.

Comment: Yes, but it *looks* like a prototype, why isn't it?

Comment: @Jens - a prototype is just a function declaration that specifies parameters.

Comment: @Jens A prototype contains a list of argument types, `void` to indicate that no arguments are accepted. `int main()` doesn't include any list.

Comment: So gcc is complaining about an old-style (K&R) function definition...that would allow `main()` to take *any* number of arguments. That's not one of the standard-sanctioned forms.

Comment: That's not an old-style function declaration.

Comment: @Jens: No. As a *definition*, `int main() { ... }` is identical to `int main(void) { ... }`; it's only different as a declaration. Either way, the definition takes no arguments, so calling it with any arguments would invoke UB. However, in the latter case, it's also a constraint violation in the scope where the declaration is visible; in the former case, it's UB but no diagnostic is required.

Comment: @R.. That makes me think. Are they identical? I find only `int main(void)` in the Standard (C99 5.1.2.2.1), not `int main()`. Isn't the latter *undefined behavior by omission*?

Comment: @Jens: No. The standard says "It shall be defined with a return type of int and with no parameters". `int main() { ... }` is a definition with return type `int` and no parameters. It does give an example with the `(void)`, but then follows with the text "or equivalent". Elsewhere the standard makes it clear that, as a definition, `()` and `(void)` are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks y'all--you make me smarter every day :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because the definition

```
int main() { /* ... */ }
```

does not include a prototype; it doesn't specify the number or type(s) of the parameters.

This:

```
int main(void) { /* ... */ }
```

does include a prototype.

With the empty parentheses, you're saying that `main` takes a fixed but unspecified number and type(s) of arguments. With `(void)`, you're explicitly saying that it takes *no* arguments.

With the former, a call like:

```
main(42);
```

will not necessarily be diagnosed.

This goes back to the pre-ANSI days before prototypes were introduced to the language, and most functions were defined with empty parentheses. Back then, it was perfectly legal to write:

```
int foo();

int foo(n)
int n;
{
    /* ... */
}

...

foo(42);
```

When prototypes were added to the language (borrowed from C++), it was necessary to keep the old meaning of empty parentheses; the "new" (this was 1989) syntax `(void)` was added so you could explicitly say that a function takes no arguments.

(C++ has different rules; it doesn't allow old-style non-prototyped functions, and empty parentheses mean that a function takes no arguments. C++ permits the `(void)` syntax for compatibility with C, but it's not generally recommended.)

Best practice is to use `(void)`, because it's more explicit. It's not entirely clear that the `int main()` form is even valid, but I've never seen a compiler that doesn't accept it.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't error - it warns. The flag says it all: it expects you to care about the arguments received by `main` (typically `int argc, char **argv)`.

Comment: Yes, it errors. The exit status is nonzero and no executable is produced.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [gcc documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) it's a warning when you added `-Wstrict-prototypes` because:

> -Wstrict-prototypes (C and Objective-C only)
>   Warn if a **function is declared or defined without specifying the argument types**. (An old-style function definition is permitted without a warning if preceded by a declaration that specifies the argument types.)

But for you it's an error because of `-Werror`:

> -Werror 
>   Make all warnings into errors.

In general, it's wrong to define a `main()` like that (regardless of what you've seen done on here), the C spec defines how `main()` must look in 5.1.2.2.1:

> The function called at program startup is named main. The implementation declares no
>   prototype for this function. It shall be defined with a return type of int and with no
>   parameters:
>
> `int main(void) { /* ... */ }`
>
> or with two parameters (referred to here as argc and argv, though any names may be
>   used, as they are local to the function in which they are declared): 
>   `int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }`

Comment: So at the end of the day, all those who write `main()` are ignorant sloppy coders who never read The Standard or do not understand the C language...? Or coming from C++ and don't know that C is a different language?

Comment: @Jens - well... I guess that's one way of putting it. I'd rather say that that all those who write `main()` are either ignorant or *lazy*. Unless you tell the compiler to slap you around for it, most of the ones I've seen just let this slide..

Comment: But doesn't it even invoke *undefined behavior*? I'd say it does since it's undefined by omission in the Standard (unless my implementation explicitly defines a non-standard way).