# How to Use Functions in C (Beginner)

Tags: c, function, variables, scope

I'm writing a program to compute the area of a rectangle. I have never written in C before but I believe I am missing a foundational aspect of understanding functions and how to pass through variables. This is what I have:

```
int computeArea(int length, int width) {
    int area;
    area = length * width;

    return(area);

}

int main() {
    printf("Enter the length and width of the rectangle: \n");
    scanf("%d %d", &length, &width);
    printf("The area of a %d by %d rectangle is %d \n", length, width, area);
}
```

On the scanf line, I receive an error of 'Use of undeclared identifier' on the variables entered. Can anyone explain to me where I have gone awry in declaring and using these variables?

Comment: Your function is correct but it looks like you forgot to call it. You also forgot to declare your variables. Note that variables declared in computeArea are not visible in main. The program also lacks necessary `#include` directives.

Comment: `int main()`!!  Is it 1987?

Comment: @WilliamPursell what's wrong with int main()?? For future note

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15796134/whats-wrong-with-int-main

Comment: @WilliamPursell As of 2018, the C standard includes two examples of `int main()` and one example of `int main(void)` (and no examples of `int main(int argc, whatever)`). In the standards committee `int main()` wins 2:1.

Comment: @n.m. http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.11.6.html . It is explicitly obsolescent.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I know. If the standard is using an obsolescent feature in example programs, why shouldn't I? I'm not more Catholic than the Pope. Besides, when the feature is finally removed, I hope and expect an empty parameter list to become synonymous with `(void)` rather than invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

some things are missing; as first things you have to define inside the main function the three variables (int length = 0, width = 0, area = 0;) that you use; then before printing the result you have to call the function (area = computeArea (length, width);) which calculates the area

```
int computeArea(int length, int width) {
    int area;
    area = length * width;

    return(area);

}

int main() {
    int length=0, width=0, area=0;
    printf("Enter the length and width of the rectangle: \n");
    scanf("%d %d", &length, &width);
    area = computeArea(length,width);
    printf("The area of a %d by %d rectangle is %d \n", length, width, area);
}
```

Comment: Answers are better if they do not just state how to do something but if they give the asker knowledge they were missing (which often requires diagnosing what the asker does not know) and explain why doing certain things work. In this case, the asker appeared not to know about the scopes of identifiers and possibly other information about how declarations work. So it would be good to explain that the declarations of `length`, `width`, and `area` in the function `computeArea` do not serve to declare them for `main`, along with some discussion of why.

Answer (score 1):

Variables shall be declared before their usages.

You forgot to declare the variables `length`, `width`, and `area` in main.

And you did not call the function.

Also as the length or the width can not be negative then the corresponding variables should be declared as `unsigned int`.

What you mean is the following

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned long long int computeArea( unsigned int length, unsigned int width ) 
{
    return ( unsigned long long int )length * width;
}

int main( void ) 
{
    unsigned int length = 0, width = 0;

    printf( "Enter the length and width of the rectangle: " );
    scanf( "%u %u", &length, &width );

    printf( "The area of a %u by %u rectangle is %llu \n", 
            length, width, computeArea( length, width ) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You must declare `length` and `width` in `main()` function.
2. You are not calling function in `main()` function. In order to use that piece of code defined as `computeArea(int length, int width)` you must call it in `main()` function. As shown below.

`computeArea(34, 56);`

Comment: Answers are better if they do not just state how to do something but if they give the asker knowledge they were missing (which often requires diagnosing what the asker does not know) and explain why doing certain things work. In this case, the asker appeared not to know about the scopes of identifiers and possibly other information about how declarations work. So it would be good to explain that the declarations of `length`, `width`, and `area` in the function `computeArea` do not serve to declare them for `main`, along with some discussion of why.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int computeArea(int length, int width) 
{
    int area;
    area = length * width;
    return(area);
}
int computeArea(int,int);
int main() 
{
    int length, width, area; //you have not defined the variables
    printf("Enter the length and width of the rectangle: \n");
    scanf("%d %d", &length, &width);
    printf("The area of a %d by %d rectangle is %d \n", length, width, area);
}
```

First you have to declare the funtion name and its return type(e.g `int` , `void`).

`int computeArea(int, int)` is a function declaration.

Also you have not declared the variables `viz`, `length`, `width`, `area`.
In C always declare the variables first in the function which you are using it.
Also you should know how functions are called and how they we can pass parameters (variables) through functions.